# Core Data Insert on Child Context creates extra instances

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am using Core Data in a multi-threaded way.  It's working fine so far and I'm quite happy and have patted myself on the back a few times.  Except one small thing.

I have for example a data model Hand.  I have another model: Finger.

A Hand as a one-to-many relationship with Finger

in my awakeFromInsert method on Hand, I have:

```
   - (void)awakeFromInsert
   {
     [super awakeFromInsert];

     if(self.fingers.count == 0)
     {
       // creates instances in current context. sets their hand to this one.
       [self addFingersToHand];  
     }
   }
```

Here's the problem.  If I create this hand on the background 'working' context, then save that and its parent contexts, it would appear that a Hand is inserted on the parent context, some fingers are also created, THEN the fingers that were created on the child context are merged, leaving 10 fingers on one hand.  O_O

Did this make sense and what have I done incorrectly?  I want to make sure that if I create a Hand it will have 5 and only 5 fingers on one hand.

Answer (score 0):

Strange. When you push up a `Hand` with 5 fingers to the parent context via `save:`, I am not even sure `awakeFromInsert` should be called. But even if it is called, `self.fingers.count` should evaluate to 5, not 0. Did you check with breakpoints what exactly is happening?

Maybe you need to check again where exactly you are inserting stuff.